# Vim: executing a visual command on startup

Tags: vim, navigation, highlight

I am aware I can select an entire line in *Vim* in *visual* mode by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. Now, can I achieve the same (i. e. placing the cursor to the specific line within a file and selecting this very line) from the shell, using only *Vim* command line options?

Currently, the best I have is

```
vim +[line] -c 'set cursorline' [file]
```

but this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the normal command `normal` to run commands in normal mode.

```
vim +[line] -c 'normal! V' [file]
```

Take a look at `:h normal`